# Possible to add a forward next behavior to css slideshow without any script?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

Possible to add a forward next behavior to this css slideshow without using any script? Also, tried to do a pause on hover by using 'animation-play-state: paused' - but I did not have any success. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

jsfiddle.net/wLgxtv6w/6

Comment: with this much code, it would be better if you created a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wLgxtv6w/6/ :)

Comment: I think you will only be able to use :active. To my knowledge that only works for the mouse down.

Comment: You can edit the question and add it, I will do it now